# ProviderScope not defined issue

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am trying to migrate an old Flutter project to Null Safety.

This is the main.dart code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:capenergy_ns/pantallas/my_home_screen.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';

import 'constantes/constantes.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var email = prefs.getString('email');

  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: EasyLocalization(
          path: "assets/translations",
          saveLocale: true,
          supportedLocales: [Locale('en', 'EN'), Locale('es', 'ES')],
          child: MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              localizationsDelegates: [
                GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              ],
              supportedLocales: [
                const Locale('es', 'ES'),
                const Locale('en', 'EN'),
              ],
              home: email == null || email == '' ? Splash2() : MyHomePage())),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Capenergy',
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

My current issue is that the line `ProviderScope(` is marked as error with this explanation:

```
The function 'ProviderScope' isn't defined
```

I think ProviderScope belongs to the package Riverpod, which is already installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And [`flutter_riverpod`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) on `pubspec.yaml`, and import `package:flutter_riverpod`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
```

Comment: What is the difference between riverpod package and flutter_riverpod package?

Comment: `riverpod`  can work with dart only

Answer (score 0):

Try installing flutter_riverpod and then import in the required file.